# How to configure haystack for elasticsearch 5.0 in django settings?

Tags: django, python-2.7, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I just upgraded elasticsearch to 5.0.0 .
I have django 1.7.7 and django-haystack 2.4.1 .

In elasticsearch 5.0.0, Authorization header has been added for security purpose.

So while making connection to elasticsearch through django, it's throwing error **elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthenticationException: TransportError(401, u'security_exception')**

Where can we add the Authorization field in haystack configuration?

Comment: Did you solved it?? because I have same error (I'm using elasticsearch5.0.0, django 1.10, django-haystack2.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

There's a separate backend that supports 1.x, 2.x and 5.x [here](https://github.com/CraveFood/django-haystack-elasticsearch). I haven't used it though, so I don't know how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Haystack doesnt support Elasticsearch 5.x (or 2.x) yet. It only supports 1.x. Its also mentioned in the their docs [here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.1/installing_search_engines.html).

2.x support is underway but as per [this](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1247#issuecomment-265126859) comment, it seems someone did try to (perhaps successfully) build an elasticsearch2 compatible backend for Haystack. [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elasticsearch2-haystack) it is.